# Capture Image of Specific area android CameraX

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax, drawrectangle

Is it possible to show a rectangle in the camera that captures the image only the rectangular part of the camera and skips all other parts?

[image]

I don't want to use any third-party library. I want to use simple CameraX.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a picture of the whole FOV then crop it.

The challenge is that the Preview and ImageCapture usually have different resolution, rotation and mirroring. To do that, you will need to transform your Preview crop rect into ImageCapture coordinate system.

You can take a look at the [CoordinateTransform](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/transform/CoordinateTransform) API provided by CameraX.

Comment: I don't want to crop it. But it should work as the QR code camera works. When qr code come inside the rectangle it detects code.

Comment: If you are using it with ImageAnalysis, then you have to manually drop the frame when the QR code is outside of the box. It still requires you to transform the coordinates though.